# Db unit tests. Constraints disabling

Tags: unit-testing, junit, unitils, database-testing

I have a set of unit tests which test my DAO layer. I have following requirements:
- For one subset of tests I need to disable constraints(foreign key, unique, not null).
- For other subset I need to remain their (I check data integrity here).

So for several test I want to enable constraints, for other to disable.

Firstly I tried to use DbMantainer(part of Unitils), because it has disable constraint option. But after that I looked into sources and found that it can only remove(through alter table) constraints at the moment when I start migration process. After constraints were removed once(before I launch first test), I can't enable their later (integrity tests).

So my questions are:
1. Can you suggest me other tools (like DbMantainer or Unitils) which can disable constraints?
2. If no such tools exist what is in your opinion the best option to disable and enable constraints in db unit testing?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: You can have a look at Acolyte (http://acolyte.eu.org/ ), which allows to provide test fixtures at JDBC level without having to manage a test DB (with all the setup/cleanup/test concurrency to managed).

Answer (score 2):

You can look into the DBUnit (Extension of JUnit)

http://java.dzone.com/articles/solve-foreign-key-problems

http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/dbunit_tip_turn_off_foreign

Thanks